# Is there a formula that copies a cell with a formula and return the outcome of that formula as a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

so basically, its Copy, Paste Special Values for lazy people.

i.e.:
Cell A5 is a date
Cell B5 is the value of the formula from Cell C3.
the outcome of Cell C3 changes everday
Cell A5 and B5 are moved down everyday
So I would like to copy Cell C3 and paste its outcome as a value.

Is there a formula for this?

Comment: This is very easy with a *VBA* macro.  Is this approach O.K. ??

Comment: Like @Gary'sStudent says this could be done via Macro, but it is certainly not possible to do with a Formula.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there's no way to do this with formulas. You *can* do it with a macro OR you can restructure your entire worksheet to calculate values for each date based on evaluating your original dataset.

First, make sure your formula in `B5` is absolute. This will keep it locked on a reference to `C3` even when it's copy / pasted elsewhere.
Relative: `=C3`
Absolute: `=$C$3`

Next, the code below will move `A5:B5` down, copy their formulas up, and then set their value to their current value instead of a formula.

```
Sub MoveDownA5B5()
    Range("A5:B5").Insert xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A6:B6").Copy Range("A5:B5")
    Range("A6:B6") = Range("A6:B6").Value
End Sub
```

As far as how this code gets run, that's up to you. You can make a button or add an automatic trigger or whatever you like. You might have to adapt it to your exact needs but this answers the core of your question.